# Mapper function in Web API Controller returns null during unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making a ASP.NET core web api and I have used Entity Framework Core. I am trying to unit test the controllers using N-Unit
I am mocking the mapper and the repository. The APIs work fine and I have even created the front end or the API but I am having issues with the unit testing.

Controller Code-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMovie(int id)
    {
        var movie = await _repo.GetMovie(id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Object with Id not found");
        }
        var movieToReturn = _mapper.Map<MovieForDetailedDto>(movie);
        return Ok(movieToReturn);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddMovie(MovieForDetailedDto movieForDetailedDto)
    { 
        if (await _repo.MovieExists(movieForDetailedDto.ATitle))
            return BadRequest("movie already exists");

        else if(!ModelState.IsValid || movieForDetailedDto.ATitle == null || movieForDetailedDto.APrice == null || movieForDetailedDto.AMovieDescription ==null)
        {
            return BadRequest("movie details not valid");
        }

        var movieToCreate = _mapper.Map<TblMovie>(movieForDetailedDto);

        var createdMovie = await _repo.AddMovie(movieToCreate);

        return Ok(createdMovie);
    }
```

In all my functions, in the line where I map the DTO to the Model, the Line returns a null object during unit testing but the they work fine outside of unit testing.

My Unit Test Code for the controller-

```
[TestFixture]
public class MoviesControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IMovieRepository> _mockMovieRepository;
    private Mock<IMapper> _mockMovieMapper;
    private MoviesController _moviesController;
    [Test]
    public async Task CallGetRequest_WhenCalledWithId_ReturnsTheMovieWithTheSameId()
    {
        getMoviesHelper getMoviesHelper = new getMoviesHelper();
        List<TblMovie> movieList = getMoviesHelper.getMovieFromList();
        var movie = getMoviesHelper.movieById(3);
        _mockMovieRepository = new Mock<IMovieRepository>();
        _mockMovieMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
        _mockMovieMapper.Setup(mapper => mapper.Map<TblMovie>(It.IsAny<MovieForDetailedDto>()))
            .Returns(getMoviesHelper.movieById(3));
        _mockMovieRepository.Setup(repo => repo.GetMovie(3))
                .ReturnsAsync(getMoviesHelper.movieById(3));
        _moviesController = new MoviesController(_mockMovieRepository.Object, _mockMovieMapper.Object);
        var tblMovie = await _moviesController.GetMovie(3);
        var okResult = tblMovie as OkObjectResult;
        //Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);
        Assert.NotNull(tblMovie);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<OkObjectResult>(tblMovie);
        var result = ((OkObjectResult)tblMovie).Value;
        var resultValue = ((OkObjectResult)tblMovie).Value as TblMovie;
        Assert.AreEqual(resultValue.ATitle,"Raging Bull");
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<TblOrder>(result);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task GivenAValidMovie_WhenIPostANewMovie_ThenItReturnsOkWithResponse()
    {
        _mockMovieRepository = new Mock<IMovieRepository>();
        _mockMovieMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
        _mockMovieMapper.Setup(mapper => mapper.Map<TblMovie>(It.IsAny<MovieForDetailedDto>()))
            .Returns(new TblMovie());
        _mockMovieRepository.Setup(repo => repo.AddMovie(It.IsAny<TblMovie>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((TblMovie movie) => movie);

        _moviesController = new MoviesController(_mockMovieRepository.Object, _mockMovieMapper.Object);
        var tblMovie = await _moviesController.AddMovie(new MovieForDetailedDto
        {
            AMovieId = 55,
            ATitle = "redemption",
            AMovieDescription = "An action comedy adventure about brilliant robotics prodigy Hiro Hamada, who finds himself in the grips of a criminal plot that threatens to destroy the fast-paced, high-tech city of San Fransokyo. With the help of his closest companion-a robot named Baymax-Hiro joins forces with a reluctant team of first-time crime fighters on a mission to save their city.",
            ADuration = "105 min",
            APrice = "10",
            APurchasePrice = "25",
            ARating = 5,
            AImageLink = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Big_Hero_6_%28film%29_poster.jpg",
            ATrailerLink = "//www.youtube.com/embed/z3biFxZIJOQ",
            AGenre = "Comedy",
            AWideImage = "https://github.com/tushar23091998/MovieRentalApp-FrontEnd/blob/master/src/app/images/bighero6.jpg?raw=true"
        });
        var okResult = tblMovie as OkObjectResult;
        Assert.AreEqual(200, okResult.StatusCode);
        Assert.NotNull(okResult);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<OkObjectResult>(tblMovie);
        var result = ((OkObjectResult)tblMovie).Value;
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<TblMovie>(result);
    }
```

In both the test cases and even in other test cases, the repo setup works fine but after defining the controller and when I call the controller function to get the value, I found in debugging that the mapper line in controller code returns null.

I am not sure how go about setting up the mockmapper now and how should I pass the value.

Debugging Output -
[image: Mapper return object value during debugging]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we were doing in unit tests, when using AutoMapper, is instead of mocking it, rather initialize it, as descried here: https://kenbonny.net/2018/01/15/injecting-automapper-profiles-in-tests/
The cons I see doing this, is that your tests might be failing because of mapping issues and are not strictly testing the method.
Given your example, your setup is incorrect.
For the get method test, you should setup to return a MovieForDetailedDto for a TblMovie, but you are doing the opposite:

```
_mockMovieMapper.Setup(mapper => mapper.Map<TblMovie>(It.IsAny<MovieForDetailedDto>())).Returns(getMoviesHelper.movieById(3));
```

should be something like:

```
var expectedMovieDto = new MovieForDetailedDto(){//insert values here}
_mockMovieMapper.Setup(mapper => mapper.Map<MovieForDetailedDto>(It.IsAny<TblMovie>())).Returns(expectedMovieDto);
```

For the POST method, you are setting it up to return a new TblMovie (so all properties are set to their default values)

```
_mockMovieMapper.Setup(mapper => mapper.Map<TblMovie>(It.IsAny<MovieForDetailedDto>())) .Returns(new TblMovie());
```

should be:

```
var expectedMovie = new TblMovie()
{
ADuration = "some value",
AGenre = "some value"
//other }

_mockMovieMapper.Setup(mapper => mapper.Map<TblMovie>(It.IsAny<MovieForDetailedDto>())).Returns(expectedMovie);
```